# Comparing runtimes of different inputs/reducing big-O magnitudes and inputs of different functions

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I’m a little bit confused on some aspects of big O notation. I apologize in advance for the convoluted example

If a function ex. `O(2^N) + O(N^7)`; the N input value is consider the same and `O(N^7)` will dominate `O(2^N)` or the big-O magnitude can be reduced to `O(N^7)` . The same would be true for  `O(2^N) * O(N^7)` ; `O(N^7)` would dominate because the value of N(or input) is consider the same and a runtime `O(N^7)` is worse than `O(2^N)`. A function would need to have two input values that scale for a function to be represented as`O(2^N) + O(M^7)` and the runtime of the input O(2^N) would dominate O(M^7). Is that correct?

Here’s where I also get mixed up. Now, if we were comparing two functions, a function with a runtime `O(N^7)` and a function with a runtime `O(2^N)`. The N’s or inputs are considered identical and function `2^N` runtime would be worse than `N^7`? We should assume the N’s are the same unless explicitly stated that they our different. Stated differently Big O is comparing the scaling value of two(for simplicity I’m using two) inputs(N) and the `N` would have to be consider identical for comparison. Am I understanding that correctly.

Any help would be appreciated or a link to a duplicate post because I'm sure this question has been asked before. I just can't find it on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "`O(2^N) + O(N^7)` ... `O(N^7)` will dominate the `O(2^N)`"

No. An exponential grows far faster than *any* polynomial.

> "The same would be true for `O(2^N) * O(N^7)`"

No. You cannot ignore non-constant *multiplicative* factors. It will grow as `O(N^7 * 2^N)`.

> "... a runtime `O(N^7)` is worse than `O(2^N)`"

Again, no.

> "Two input values ... `O(2^N) + O(M^7)` ... `O(2^N)` would dominate `O(M^7)`"

This is correct, although only if `M` is not some exponential of `N`.

---

In conclusion, I recommend reading up on big-O. You don't seem to have grasped the concept of *asymptotic growth*.

Comment: thank god you answered. I was reading an online blog from a company that provides technical education services for software engineers and read their explanation on big O. I thought to myself that their explanation made absolutely no sense because they wrote that this O(N^7) would grow faster than O(2^N). I don't have a formal education in cs and I've discovered that there are a lot of bad resources out there. I assumed they were correct because they provide cs educational services, what a joke company. Thank you for clearing that up.